# is Geforce Experience viable for maintaining GPU drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia-geforce

I'm using Geforce Experience to update my Nvidia GPU drivers whenever a new  release arrives. I don't let it install automatically, and I do use a custom clean install with only drivers and PhysX. However, most guides on this matter say that I should update computer drivers manually, because automated tools are not that suitable for this. Is this also true of the Experience tool?

Comment: Yes;  this application also allows you to use hardware to record or steam to twitch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I'm not sure what "guides" you're referring to, I'm guessing that when people recommend manually updating drivers (or software), they're saying that you should initiate the installation, instead of letting it happen auto-magically in the background.

This advice is mainly so that you're aware of your system configuration, and if something breaks, it's easy for you to know, "Oh, I just upgraded my video driver an hour ago, and now I'm seeing all black . . . I should rollback my driver . . . "

It sounds like you're using the Geforce software to get notifications, and then manually installing the driver, which would correspond to the "guides" you've read.